# General Solution for a system of 4 equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Consider the following system of equations:

$$e_1^1+e_1^2K=e_1^3J+e_1^4G\tag{1}$$

$$e_2^1J+e_2^2G=e_2^3T\tag{2}$$

$$e_3^1+e_3^2K=e_3^3J+e_3^4G\tag{3}$$

$$e_4^1J+e_4^2G=e_4^3T\tag{4}$$

where $e_n^m$ , $n,m=1,2,3,4$ are constants. I tried many times to solve it for $T$ by myself but I couldn't. I also looked for software to get a general solution for such system of equations but I didn't find any. I tried with equations (3) and (4) and I just got the following equations;

$$J=\frac{e_4^3 e_2^2-e_4^2 e_2^3}{e_4^1 e_2^2-e_4^2 e_2^1}T$$

$$G=\frac{e_4^3 e_2^1-e_4^1 e_2^3}{e_4^2 e_2^1-e_4^1 e_2^2}T$$

I don't know how I should continue to get the general solution for $T$ in term of $e_n^m$. Can anyone here help me out please?

Comment: Shouldn't be that hard. If I'm not mistaken $e^m_n$ are constants so why don't you give them 'better' names.

Comment: can you solve it for me @Daniel, because i really cannot work out with systems of equations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system is, up to relabelling,
$$
\begin{array}{c}
a_{11}G &+a_{12}J& +a_{13}K& +0T &= & x_1 \\
a_{21}G &+a_{22}J& +0K& +a_{24}T &= & 0 \\
a_{31}G &+a_{32}J& +a_{33}K& +0T &= & x_3 \\
a_{41}G &+a_{42}J& +0K& +a_{44}T &= & 0
\end{array}
$$
which is equivalent to the matrix equation $M v = x$,
$$
\left[\begin{array}{c}
a_{11} &a_{12}& a_{13}& 0  \\
a_{21} &a_{22}& 0& a_{24}  \\
a_{31} &a_{32}& a_{33}& 0  \\
a_{41} &a_{42}& 0& a_{44} 
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c} G\\ J \\ K \\ T \end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c} x_1 \\ 0 \\ x_3 \\ 0 \end{array}\right]
$$
It has a unique solution iff
$$\det M = a_{11} a_{22} a_{33} a_{44} - a_{11} a_{24} a_{33} a_{42} - a_{12} a_{21} a_{33} a_{44} + a_{12} a_{24} a_{33} a_{41} + a_{13} a_{21} a_{32} a_{44} - a_{13} a_{22} a_{31} a_{44} + a_{13} a_{24} a_{31} a_{42} - a_{13} a_{24} a_{32} a_{41}\neq 0$$

And the solution spat out by [sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/matrices.html?highlight=matrix%20solve#sympy.matrices.matrices.MatrixBase.solve)'s `M.solve(Matrix([x1,0,x3,0]))` is
$$ \left[\begin{array}{c} G\\ J \\ K \\ T \end{array}\right] = \displaystyle \left[\begin{matrix}\frac{\left(- \left(a_{12} a_{13} a_{21} + a_{13} \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right)\right) \left(a_{21} x_{1} \left(a_{11} a_{32} - a_{12} a_{31}\right) + \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right) \left(a_{11} x_{3} - a_{31} x_{1}\right)\right) + \left(a_{12} a_{21} x_{1} + x_{1} \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right)\right) \left(a_{13} a_{21} \left(a_{11} a_{32} - a_{12} a_{31}\right) + \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right) \left(a_{11} a_{33} - a_{13} a_{31}\right)\right)\right) \left(a_{11} a_{24} \left(a_{11} a_{32} - a_{12} a_{31}\right) \left(a_{13} a_{21} \left(a_{11} a_{42} - a_{12} a_{41}\right) - a_{13} a_{41} \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right)\right) + \left(- a_{11} a_{24} \left(a_{11} a_{42} - a_{12} a_{41}\right) + a_{11} a_{44} \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right)\right) \left(a_{13} a_{21} \left(a_{11} a_{32} - a_{12} a_{31}\right) + \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right) \left(a_{11} a_{33} - a_{13} a_{31}\right)\right)\right) - \left(\left(a_{13} a_{21} \left(a_{11} a_{32} - a_{12} a_{31}\right) + \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right) \left(a_{11} a_{33} - a_{13} a_{31}\right)\right) \left(a_{21} x_{1} \left(a_{11} a_{42} - a_{12} a_{41}\right) - a_{41} x_{1} \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right)\right) - \left(a_{13} a_{21} \left(a_{11} a_{42} - a_{12} a_{41}\right) - a_{13} a_{41} \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right)\right) \left(a_{21} x_{1} \left(a_{11} a_{32} - a_{12} a_{31}\right) + \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right) \left(a_{11} x_{3} - a_{31} x_{1}\right)\right)\right) \left(- a_{11} a_{12} a_{24} \left(a_{13} a_{21} \left(a_{11} a_{32} - a_{12} a_{31}\right) + \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right) \left(a_{11} a_{33} - a_{13} a_{31}\right)\right) + a_{11} a_{24} \left(a_{11} a_{32} - a_{12} a_{31}\right) \left(a_{12} a_{13} a_{21} + a_{13} \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right)\right)\right)}{a_{11} \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right) \left(a_{13} a_{21} \left(a_{11} a_{32} - a_{12} a_{31}\right) + \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right) \left(a_{11} a_{33} - a_{13} a_{31}\right)\right) \left(a_{11} a_{24} \left(a_{11} a_{32} - a_{12} a_{31}\right) \left(a_{13} a_{21} \left(a_{11} a_{42} - a_{12} a_{41}\right) - a_{13} a_{41} \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right)\right) + \left(- a_{11} a_{24} \left(a_{11} a_{42} - a_{12} a_{41}\right) + a_{11} a_{44} \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right)\right) \left(a_{13} a_{21} \left(a_{11} a_{32} - a_{12} a_{31}\right) + \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right) \left(a_{11} a_{33} - a_{13} a_{31}\right)\right)\right)}\\\frac{- \left(\left(a_{13} a_{21} \left(a_{11} a_{32} - a_{12} a_{31}\right) + \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right) \left(a_{11} a_{33} - a_{13} a_{31}\right)\right) \left(a_{21} x_{1} \left(a_{11} a_{42} - a_{12} a_{41}\right) - a_{41} x_{1} \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right)\right) - \left(a_{13} a_{21} \left(a_{11} a_{42} - a_{12} a_{41}\right) - a_{13} a_{41} \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right)\right) \left(a_{21} x_{1} \left(a_{11} a_{32} - a_{12} a_{31}\right) + \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right) \left(a_{11} x_{3} - a_{31} x_{1}\right)\right)\right) \left(- a_{11} a_{13} a_{21} a_{24} \left(a_{11} a_{32} - a_{12} a_{31}\right) + a_{11} a_{24} \left(a_{13} a_{21} \left(a_{11} a_{32} - a_{12} a_{31}\right) + \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right) \left(a_{11} a_{33} - a_{13} a_{31}\right)\right)\right) + \left(a_{13} a_{21} \left(a_{21} x_{1} \left(a_{11} a_{32} - a_{12} a_{31}\right) + \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right) \left(a_{11} x_{3} - a_{31} x_{1}\right)\right) - a_{21} x_{1} \left(a_{13} a_{21} \left(a_{11} a_{32} - a_{12} a_{31}\right) + \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right) \left(a_{11} a_{33} - a_{13} a_{31}\right)\right)\right) \left(a_{11} a_{24} \left(a_{11} a_{32} - a_{12} a_{31}\right) \left(a_{13} a_{21} \left(a_{11} a_{42} - a_{12} a_{41}\right) - a_{13} a_{41} \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right)\right) + \left(- a_{11} a_{24} \left(a_{11} a_{42} - a_{12} a_{41}\right) + a_{11} a_{44} \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right)\right) \left(a_{13} a_{21} \left(a_{11} a_{32} - a_{12} a_{31}\right) + \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right) \left(a_{11} a_{33} - a_{13} a_{31}\right)\right)\right)}{\left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right) \left(a_{13} a_{21} \left(a_{11} a_{32} - a_{12} a_{31}\right) + \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right) \left(a_{11} a_{33} - a_{13} a_{31}\right)\right) \left(a_{11} a_{24} \left(a_{11} a_{32} - a_{12} a_{31}\right) \left(a_{13} a_{21} \left(a_{11} a_{42} - a_{12} a_{41}\right) - a_{13} a_{41} \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right)\right) + \left(- a_{11} a_{24} \left(a_{11} a_{42} - a_{12} a_{41}\right) + a_{11} a_{44} \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right)\right) \left(a_{13} a_{21} \left(a_{11} a_{32} - a_{12} a_{31}\right) + \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right) \left(a_{11} a_{33} - a_{13} a_{31}\right)\right)\right)}\\\frac{a_{11} a_{24} \left(a_{11} a_{32} - a_{12} a_{31}\right) \left(\left(a_{13} a_{21} \left(a_{11} a_{32} - a_{12} a_{31}\right) + \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right) \left(a_{11} a_{33} - a_{13} a_{31}\right)\right) \left(a_{21} x_{1} \left(a_{11} a_{42} - a_{12} a_{41}\right) - a_{41} x_{1} \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right)\right) - \left(a_{13} a_{21} \left(a_{11} a_{42} - a_{12} a_{41}\right) - a_{13} a_{41} \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right)\right) \left(a_{21} x_{1} \left(a_{11} a_{32} - a_{12} a_{31}\right) + \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right) \left(a_{11} x_{3} - a_{31} x_{1}\right)\right)\right) + \left(a_{21} x_{1} \left(a_{11} a_{32} - a_{12} a_{31}\right) + \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right) \left(a_{11} x_{3} - a_{31} x_{1}\right)\right) \left(a_{11} a_{24} \left(a_{11} a_{32} - a_{12} a_{31}\right) \left(a_{13} a_{21} \left(a_{11} a_{42} - a_{12} a_{41}\right) - a_{13} a_{41} \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right)\right) + \left(- a_{11} a_{24} \left(a_{11} a_{42} - a_{12} a_{41}\right) + a_{11} a_{44} \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right)\right) \left(a_{13} a_{21} \left(a_{11} a_{32} - a_{12} a_{31}\right) + \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right) \left(a_{11} a_{33} - a_{13} a_{31}\right)\right)\right)}{\left(a_{13} a_{21} \left(a_{11} a_{32} - a_{12} a_{31}\right) + \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right) \left(a_{11} a_{33} - a_{13} a_{31}\right)\right) \left(a_{11} a_{24} \left(a_{11} a_{32} - a_{12} a_{31}\right) \left(a_{13} a_{21} \left(a_{11} a_{42} - a_{12} a_{41}\right) - a_{13} a_{41} \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right)\right) + \left(- a_{11} a_{24} \left(a_{11} a_{42} - a_{12} a_{41}\right) + a_{11} a_{44} \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right)\right) \left(a_{13} a_{21} \left(a_{11} a_{32} - a_{12} a_{31}\right) + \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right) \left(a_{11} a_{33} - a_{13} a_{31}\right)\right)\right)}\\\frac{\left(a_{13} a_{21} \left(a_{11} a_{32} - a_{12} a_{31}\right) + \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right) \left(a_{11} a_{33} - a_{13} a_{31}\right)\right) \left(a_{21} x_{1} \left(a_{11} a_{42} - a_{12} a_{41}\right) - a_{41} x_{1} \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right)\right) - \left(a_{13} a_{21} \left(a_{11} a_{42} - a_{12} a_{41}\right) - a_{13} a_{41} \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right)\right) \left(a_{21} x_{1} \left(a_{11} a_{32} - a_{12} a_{31}\right) + \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right) \left(a_{11} x_{3} - a_{31} x_{1}\right)\right)}{a_{11} a_{24} \left(a_{11} a_{32} - a_{12} a_{31}\right) \left(a_{13} a_{21} \left(a_{11} a_{42} - a_{12} a_{41}\right) - a_{13} a_{41} \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right)\right) + \left(- a_{11} a_{24} \left(a_{11} a_{42} - a_{12} a_{41}\right) + a_{11} a_{44} \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right)\right) \left(a_{13} a_{21} \left(a_{11} a_{32} - a_{12} a_{31}\right) + \left(a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}\right) \left(a_{11} a_{33} - a_{13} a_{31}\right)\right)}\end{matrix}\right]$$

running `simplify()` gives

$$ \left[\begin{array}{c} G\\ J \\ K \\ T \end{array}\right] = \displaystyle \left[\begin{matrix}\frac{- a_{13} a_{22} a_{44} x_{3} + a_{13} a_{24} a_{42} x_{3} + a_{22} a_{33} a_{44} x_{1} - a_{24} a_{33} a_{42} x_{1}}{a_{11} a_{22} a_{33} a_{44} - a_{11} a_{24} a_{33} a_{42} - a_{12} a_{21} a_{33} a_{44} + a_{12} a_{24} a_{33} a_{41} + a_{13} a_{21} a_{32} a_{44} - a_{13} a_{22} a_{31} a_{44} + a_{13} a_{24} a_{31} a_{42} - a_{13} a_{24} a_{32} a_{41}}\\\frac{a_{13} a_{21} a_{44} x_{3} - a_{13} a_{24} a_{41} x_{3} - a_{21} a_{33} a_{44} x_{1} + a_{24} a_{33} a_{41} x_{1}}{a_{11} a_{22} a_{33} a_{44} - a_{11} a_{24} a_{33} a_{42} - a_{12} a_{21} a_{33} a_{44} + a_{12} a_{24} a_{33} a_{41} + a_{13} a_{21} a_{32} a_{44} - a_{13} a_{22} a_{31} a_{44} + a_{13} a_{24} a_{31} a_{42} - a_{13} a_{24} a_{32} a_{41}}\\\frac{a_{11} a_{22} a_{44} x_{3} - a_{11} a_{24} a_{42} x_{3} - a_{12} a_{21} a_{44} x_{3} + a_{12} a_{24} a_{41} x_{3} + a_{21} a_{32} a_{44} x_{1} - a_{22} a_{31} a_{44} x_{1} + a_{24} a_{31} a_{42} x_{1} - a_{24} a_{32} a_{41} x_{1}}{a_{11} a_{22} a_{33} a_{44} - a_{11} a_{24} a_{33} a_{42} - a_{12} a_{21} a_{33} a_{44} + a_{12} a_{24} a_{33} a_{41} + a_{13} a_{21} a_{32} a_{44} - a_{13} a_{22} a_{31} a_{44} + a_{13} a_{24} a_{31} a_{42} - a_{13} a_{24} a_{32} a_{41}}\\\frac{- a_{13} a_{21} a_{42} x_{3} + a_{13} a_{22} a_{41} x_{3} + a_{21} a_{33} a_{42} x_{1} - a_{22} a_{33} a_{41} x_{1}}{a_{11} a_{22} a_{33} a_{44} - a_{11} a_{24} a_{33} a_{42} - a_{12} a_{21} a_{33} a_{44} + a_{12} a_{24} a_{33} a_{41} + a_{13} a_{21} a_{32} a_{44} - a_{13} a_{22} a_{31} a_{44} + a_{13} a_{24} a_{31} a_{42} - a_{13} a_{24} a_{32} a_{41}}\end{matrix}\right] $$

In particular, $T$ is
$$T=\frac{- a_{13} a_{21} a_{42} x_{3} + a_{13} a_{22} a_{41} x_{3} + a_{21} a_{33} a_{42} x_{1} - a_{22} a_{33} a_{41} x_{1}}{(a_{11} a_{22} a_{33} a_{44} - a_{11} a_{24} a_{33} a_{42} - a_{12} a_{21} a_{33} a_{44} + a_{12} a_{24} a_{33} a_{41} + a_{13} a_{21} a_{32} a_{44} - a_{13} a_{22} a_{31} a_{44} + a_{13} a_{24} a_{31} a_{42} - a_{13} a_{24} a_{32} a_{41})}.$$

i.e. $$ T=\frac{- a_{13} a_{21} a_{42} x_{3} + a_{13} a_{22} a_{41} x_{3} + a_{21} a_{33} a_{42} x_{1} - a_{22} a_{33} a_{41} x_{1}}{\det M}.$$

The full code to be put into eg a Jupyter Notebook:

```
#uncomment next line if using IDLE
#from sympy import *
a11,a12,a13,a14,a21,a22,a23,a24,a31,a32,a33,a34,a41,a42,a43,a44 = symbols('a11 a12 a13 a14 a21 a22 a23 a24 a31 a32 a33 a34 a41 a42 a43 a44 ')
x1,x2,x3,x4=symbols('x1 x2 x3 x4')
M=Matrix([[a11, a12, a13, 0],[a21, a22, 0, a24],[a31,a32,a33,0],[a41,a42,0,a44]])
M.det() 
V=M.solve(Matrix([x1,0,x3,0]))
V2=V.simplify()
T=V2[3]
T
```

Sympy has an [online shell](https://live.sympy.org) but the above code times out, so one will need a local installation.

Answer (score 1):

$$(1)e_1^3J+e_1^4G-e_1^2K +0T = e_1^1$$

$$(3)e_3^3J+e_3^4G - e_3^2K + 0 T = - e_3^1$$

$$(2)e_2^1J+e_2^2G + 0K - e_2^3T = 0 $$

$$(4)e_4^1J+e_4^2G + 0K - e_4^3T= 0 $$

$$\begin{bmatrix}e_1^3,  e_1^4,  -e_1^2,  0 \\
e_3^3, e_3^4,  - e_3^2,   0 \\
e_2^1, e_2^2,  0, - e_2^3 \\
e_4^1, e_4^2, 0, - e_4^3
 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} J \\ G \\ K \\ T\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$

Denote $$E = \begin{bmatrix}e_1^3,  e_1^4,  -e_1^2,  0 \\
e_3^3, e_3^4,  - e_3^2,   0 \\
e_2^1, e_2^2,  0, - e_2^3 \\
e_4^1, e_4^2, 0, - e_4^3
 \end{bmatrix}$$

Then,
$$\begin{bmatrix} J \\ G \\ K \\ T\end{bmatrix} = E^{-1}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$

You need to find $E^{-1}$

Here is an example for finding inverse for $4\times 4$ matrix https://semath.info/src/inverse-cofactor-ex4.html you can replace your coefficient on the final row and the determinant there, then you will get your answer for T.